# How to simplify output redirection command line?

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script, busybox

I have frequently used output redirection commands in my Linux environment, for example,

```
echo mymodule set number 10 >/proc/aaaa/bbbb_cmd
```

And I want to omit the `echo .... >....` and use this command like

```
mymodule set number 10
```

I have been told that bash can do that, but I don't know how to? Can someone give me an example?

Comment: How about using an alias? `$> alias setnum='mymodule set ....; $>setnum`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems as if you would be best served by a shell function:

```bsh
mymodule () {
    local IFS=' '
    printf 'mymodule %s\n' "$*" >/proc/aaaa/bbbb_cmd
}
```

This defines the shell function `mymodule`.  It will write the string `mymodule` followed by whatever other strings you give it on the command line, space-delimited to `/proc/aaaa/bbbb_cmd`.

The `"$*"` will be expanded to the list of command-line arguments, concatenated with the first character of `$IFS` as the delimiter (a space by default, but we explicitly set it to space here so that function still works in contexts where `$IFS` has been modified) into a single string.

The shell function definition could be placed wherever you ordinarily put aliases or in your `~/.bashrc` or equivalent file.  The function would be available in the next shell session that you start.

You would use this shell function like how you show in the question:

```bsh
mymodule set number 10
```

Comment: Or with `zsh`: `mymodule mymodule2...() print -r -- "$0" "$@" > /proc/aaaa/bbbb_cmd`